# Show NA values + change the color range | ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, grid, heatmap

I have an input file `file1.txt`:

```
rs113565588 SIFT    0.306
rs113565588 Polyphen2   0
rs113565588 MutationAssessor    0.345
rs61729896  SIFT    NA
rs61729896  Polyphen2   NA
rs61729896  MutationAssessor    NA
rs61755283  SIFT    NA
rs61755283  Polyphen2   NA
rs61755283  MutationAssessor    NA
rs777439738 SIFT    NA
rs777439738 Polyphen2   NA
rs777439738 MutationAssessor    NA
```

And this is my R code to plot this table as a heatmap:

```
library(ggplot2)
mydata <- read.table("file1.txt", header=FALSE, 
                     sep="\t")

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill=V3)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_text(aes(V1, V2, label = V3), color = "black", size = 4)
```

And this the plot I got:

[image]

I need to:

1. Label `NA` values as well, rather than leave them as a gray blank;
2. Change the color range rather than this default one.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ for scale_color_* geoms to adjust colors. How exactly do you want to present NA values?

Comment: As the numbers, a gray square have NA written inside. @RomanLuštrik

Comment: I would add [annotation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html) for those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following can get you started:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = V3)) + 
  geom_text(data = . %>% mutate(V3 = ifelse(is.na(V3), "NA", as.character(V3))),
            aes(label = V3), 
            color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "gold", high = "firebrick4", na.value = "grey")
```

[image: plot]

Explanations:

1. `x = V1, y = V2` are common aesthetic mappings shared across both geom layers. Leave them in `ggplot()` to avoid typing for each layer.
2. `fill = V3` is only needed for `geom_tile()`. Place it there rather than the main one, as we do not need `geom_text()` to inherit it as well.
3. We want NA values to be interpreted as "NA" *for labels only*, so we modify the dataset passed to `geom_text()`. `data = .` refers to the data inherited from the main `ggplot()`. `. %>% mutate(...)` uses the pipe operator & mutate function from dplyr package to convert NA values to "NA". If you prefer some other label, you can use that as well.
4. `scale_fill_gradient()` allows you to set different colours for the two ends of the scale, as well as change the fill colour for NA values. Here is a handy [lookup table for colour names recognised in R](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour).